# Two Different Javascript Alerts before redirecting in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, redirect, alert

I want to show different alert messages using JavaScript. Here is my code, but my alert box will not show before the redirect. I tried the other examples provided but those are all using just one type of alert message. I use this ShowAlertMessage method to show other types of warnings as well, in which I don't want to redirect to any other page. Just give the user a warning.

```
If (user creates a new work order)
{
    ShowAlertMessage("Property work order " + txtWorkOrderNumber.Text + " created successfully");
}
else
    ShowAlertMessage("Property work order updated successfully");

Response.Redirect("~/DashBoard.aspx");


public static void ShowAlertMessage(string msg)
{
     Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;

     if (page != null)
     {
           string script = "alert(\"'" + msg + "'\");";
           ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), "err_msg", script, true);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're sending a `Response.Redirect`, which means your response does not have any content, but rather just the URL to redirect to.

In order to do what you're trying to do, you'd have to write out the javascript to the current page, then once the alerts fire, use javascript to move to a new URL.

Maybe something like the following:

```
string script = string.Format("alert('{0}'); window.location.href='{1}';",
    msg, ResolveUrl("~/Dashboard.aspx"));
```

This is a common example of a problem with WebForms - it's very difficult to properly mix client and server code together to provide a good user experience, which is why I much prefer doing my user experience stuff completely in javascript, with AJAX to do most of the posts.

Comment: The thing is I don't want to include my Response.Redirect within the   ShowAlertMessage, because I use this method for other warnings as well in which I don't need to redirect the user to any other page.